# Why my volume nodes not working in blender?

Tags: volumetrics

I tried experimenting with volume nodes in blender but none of then seem to work. Every node just produces a rough volume cube. This includes for every type of volume node like Principled Volume, Volume Scatter etc.

Comment: are you doing it in Cycles or Eevee? Eevee is still limited, you can't use volumetrics for other shapes than cubes, plus you only see a preview so you need to increase the sampling I guess

Answer (score 1):

Eevee is still limited, you can't use volumetrics for other shapes than cubes, plus keep in mind that you need to increase the *Sampling* to get a better result. Also play with the *Volumetrics > Tile Size*, lower looks better, and *Samples*:

[image]

That said, you have new objects, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Volume > Empty* that allow you to create custom volumetric shapes. Once created, give it a modifier > *Mesh to Volume*, in your scene select an object as *Object* of your modifier, then hide the object, and you have your custom volumetric:

[image]

Comment: Also makes sure you connect the output of principled volume to volume input of material output and not the surface(I do that all that).

Comment: yes actually we lack informations on his problem   ;)

Comment: Ah Yes, but he is a new contributor so we can cut him some slack

Comment: Thanks for the information